# objective c dynamic value assign

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

```
NSString *one = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"1",@"id",@"Test1",@"text", nil];
    NSString *two = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"2",@"id",@"Test2",@"text", nil];
    NSString *three = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"3",@"id",@"Test3",@"text", nil];

    _options = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:one,two,three,nil];
```

This is the code i am using and running properly in my code. Now i want it dynamically, like

```
int total = 20;
    NSMutableArray *arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for(int x = 0; x < total; x++)
    {
        [arr addObject:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"1",@"id",@"Test1",@"text", nil]];
    }
```

But it's not working. Can anyone help me out of this.

The main code is like

```
_options = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"1",@"id",@"Test1",@"text", nil],[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"1",@"id",@"Test1",@"text", nil],[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"1",@"id",@"Test1",@"text", nil],nil];
```

and i want to create it dynamically ,like the value will go for 1-100. How can i do that

Comment: **What** do you want to be dynamic in it?

Comment: I mean, in what sense do you want it to be dynamic? The values in the dictionary? Or what else?

Comment: Actually i am assigning this " _options" value and open it in a popup like list view. So i need value on it

Comment: NString = NSDictionary ain't going to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably ran into an issue trying to put primitives into the NSDictionary, which isn't possible. Turn your values into strings.

```
for(int x = 1; x <= 100; x++) {
    NSString* object1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", x];
    NSString* object3 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Test%d", x];
    [arr addObject:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:object1,@"id",object3,@"text", nil]];
}
[_options addObjectsFromArray:arr];
```

Comment: actually the main code is _options = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"1",@"id",@"Test1",@"text", nil],[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"1",@"id",@"Test1",@"text", nil],[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"1",@"id",@"Test1",@"text", nil],nil]; and i want to dynamic this, like value should be one to 100. can u help me out plz

Comment: If you make `total` a value of 100, that's what my answer will do, insert a value from 1 to 100 where you have numbers.

Comment: didn't get ur point my friend. can i have some example plz

Comment: I edited again, is that any easier? Don't think I can do much more than that, copy, paste, and you're set.

Answer (score 1):

You should:

```
int total = 20;
    NSMutableArray *arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for(int x = 0; x < total; x++)
    {
          NSString *idStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", x+1];
          [arr addObject:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: idStr,@"id",@"Test1",@"text", nil]];
    }
```